# How would you perform this query?

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|User input     | Responce                  |
|               |                           |
|I hate my self | Oh no, I feel sad for you |
+-------------------------------------------+

How would you query if the user input:
"I want to tell you that I hate my self"

the query found phrase "I hate my self" so

Output: "Oh no, i feel sad for you".
```

BUT

```
If the user input:
"I want to tell you that I hate you" 
OR 
"I hate"

Output: NULL / No data found
```

I tried SQL QUERY: MATCH AGAINST ...

but when i enter only "I hate", it returns

Output: "Oh no, i feel sad for you". it must return nothing coz the phrase is

not equal on the data on the database "I hate my self".

Thanks for HELP ... What is the proper query on this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT Response FROM mytable WHERE 'I Hate Myself' LIKE CONCAT('%', UserInput, '%');
```

Comment: that should be 'I hate my self' - noticed too late to edit.

Comment: Didn't work sir, whats the purpose of your concatenation?

Comment: It worked on the test I did - have you checked for case-sensitivity. The concatenation adds the wildcard character to either side of the contents of the UserInput field so it is search for that string any where in the input string.

Comment: See this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecaa3/1. (Note I accidentally entered _"my self"_ rather than _"myself"_.

Comment: When I enter "I hate" .. it returns "Oh no, i feel sad for you" which is wrong to my query, it must not return any string since there is no phrase "i hate" in the table data... Any other idea sir?

HERE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06703/9

Comment: Check out my answer carefully - you have the values for the LIKE comparison reversed - it needs to be exactly as I wrote it - in your case : _"'i hate' LIKE CONCAT('%', question, '%') LIMIT 1"_ - use my SQL fiddle & see what you get. (I will be on holiday for a week so can no longer help)

Comment: As a quick note - CONCAT joins all of the string parameters together, so passing just one parameter as you do in you SQL fiddle does nothing other than return the original string.